# android markers from database using php and mysql what is the best method

Tags: php, android, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am building an app in android studio basically a kind of a app which will show many markers to the user, the markers are also created by the users.

Basically its my first time with the android studio and I don't want to mess up things, and posting a question here so I can get a voice of experience and be precaution while developing the code.

My application will use php pages to save data and fetch data from mysql database, I just want to know as the user will increase so does the pointers what is the best method to call those pointer in my application,

Json ?
or is there any other way I can do it, the best practice considering there will be lots of markers.

Is it a good idea to restrict markers to the window view, does the increase in code will increase the load in server or how much time it will usually take to load further data when screen is moved.

If I load all the markers at same time, is there any chance of lagging and utilizing resource of phone and server ?

I believe you guys will guide me the best possible practice I can utilize thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JSON data with latitude longitude value:

```
    [
    {
        "name": "New York",
        "latlng": [
            62.457434,
            17.349869
        ],
        "population": "123"
    },
    {
        "name": "Dhaka",
        "latlng": [
            62.455102,
            17.345599
        ],
        "population": "132"
    },
]
```

it is better to load all marker data during map load, because if u want to load data based on user's map location change it will call network api in every time use touch on map which will lag the UI.

you can load all data In a worker thread since it's a network operation. so UI will not be slow.

Here is a sample code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "ExampleApp";

    private static final String SERVICE_URL = "YOUR SERVICE URL";

    protected GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (map == null) {
            map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            if (map != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {
        // Retrieve the city data from the web service
        // In a worker thread since it's a network operation.
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    retrieveAndAddCities();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot retrieve cities", e);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    protected void retrieveAndAddCities() throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        final StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            // Connect to the web service
            URL url = new URL(SERVICE_URL);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            // Read the JSON data into the StringBuilder
            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                json.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to service", e);
            throw new IOException("Error connecting to service", e);
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

        // Create markers for the city data.
        // Must run this on the UI thread since it's a UI operation.
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    createMarkersFromJson(json.toString());
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing JSON", e);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    void createMarkersFromJson(String json) throws JSONException {
        // De-serialize the JSON string into an array of city objects
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            // Create a marker for each city in the JSON data.
            JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title(jsonObj.getString("name"))
                .snippet(Integer.toString(jsonObj.getInt("population")))
                .position(new LatLng(
                        jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(0),
                        jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(1)
                 ))
            );
        }
    }
}
```